# Why is one (big) reqeust bringing down my Apache Server?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, web-server

I have a few large files on my server (namely a txt file with 32 million digits of pi in it) on my webserver, and occasionally when I access it in a web browser, it might work once or twice, but if I access it any more than that, it seems to crash. What's weird is that the server itself isn't crashing (and I don't even think Apache is crashing) but all of a sudden, the server stops serving content (I usually get a timeout error). The server itself has got decent performance. Does anyone know why this keeps happening?

Comment: Are you calcuating 32 million digits every time, or is it just serving a flat file that contains the 32 million digits?

Comment: Just serving a static text file with the digits. Definitely not generating every time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just your browser that is having trouble rendering 32 million digits of π on the screen.

Comment: The same sort of thing happens when I spam refresh a page or ping flood my server - it doesn't go down, but it stops responding... Could it be my gateway trying to block an what it thinks is an "attack"?